# How to update multiple checked records using stand alone textbox in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

**PHP** - Here is my PHP code (New to PHP). I'm trying to update the multiple records selected using checkbox with the values in two textboxes.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_bulk_result']) == "Submit") {
    $test_date = $_REQUEST['test_date'];
    $user_role;
    $id = $_POST['selector'];
    echo $id;
    $N = count($id);
    echo $N;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $N; $i++) {
    $get_data       = "select * from test where test_name='$id[$i]' && test_date='$test_date' && run_type='$run_type' && test_run_name='$test_run_name' && assignee='$name'";
     $get_data1      = mysqli_query($dbcon, $get_data);
     $get_count      = mysqli_num_rows($get_data1);
     $failure_reason = $_POST['reason_failure_bulk'];
     echo $failure_reason;
     echo $action_taken;
     $action_taken = $_POST['action_taken_bulk'];
     for ($i = 1; $i <= $get_count; $i++) {
     $test_name = $_POST['test_name' . "$i"];
     $update_reason_for_test  = "update test set failure_reason='$reason_failure_bulk',action_taken='$action_taken_bulk' where assignee='$name' and test_name='$test_name' && test_status!='ok' && test_date='$test_date' && run_type='$run_type' && test_run_name='$test_run_name'";
     $update_reason_for_test1 = mysqli_query($dbcon, $update_reason_for_test);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**HTML** - Here is my HTML for two textboxes and checkbox. Sorry I couldn't paste the whole code.

```
<form name="update_result_2" id="update_result_2" action="" method="post" style="margin: auto; text-align: center; display: block;">
<tr colspan=7 align="center">
<td colspan=3 align="center"><b>Bulk Update Reason</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="reason_failure_bulk" value="reason_failure_bulk"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="action_taken_bulk" value="action_taken_bulk"></td>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name='submit_bulk_result' id="submit_bulk_result" value="BULK SUBMIT" class="btn" style="padding: 4px 20px;background:#ffae00;background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffae00, #d67600);background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffae00, #d67600);background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffae00, #d67600);background: linear-gradient(top, #ffae00, #d67600);border:2px outset #dad9d8;font-family:Andika, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:1.1em;letter-spacing:0.05em;text-transform:uppercase;color:#fff;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 10px #000;-webkit-border-radius: 15px;-moz-border-radius: 15px;border-radius: 15px;-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .55) 0 1px 6px;-moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .55) 0 1px 6px;
box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .55) 0 1px 6px;">
</td></tr>
</form>
<td><input name="selector[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $get_data2['test_name'] ?>"></td></tr>
```

Please assist me - No row has been selected in while pulling things using checkbox and Value from textbox is also not showing up- This is why no row has been updated which I'm trying to do with the above code.

Comment: Start by changing `if (isset($_POST['submit_bulk_result']) == "Submit") {` to `if (!empty($_POST['submit_bulk_result'])) {` and make sure you enable error reporting in PHP. Because if you had done that already, you would've known that line is invalid PHP code and therefor your form never gets handled (it never passes your if-statement).

Answer (score 0):

`isset` will return `true` or `false` so cahnge you condition

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_bulk_result']) == "Submit") {
```

to

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_bulk_result'])) { //which will check submit button clicked or not
```

Also your `selector` input is outside `form` element So put it inside `form`

```
<form name="update_result_2" id="update_result_2" action="" method="post" style="margin: auto; text-align: center; display: block;">
<tr colspan=7 align="center">
<td colspan=3 align="center"><b>Bulk Update Reason</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="reason_failure_bulk" value="reason_failure_bulk"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="action_taken_bulk" value="action_taken_bulk"></td>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name='submit_bulk_result' id="submit_bulk_result" value="BULK SUBMIT" class="btn" style="padding: 4px 20px;background:#ffae00;background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffae00, #d67600);background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffae00, #d67600);background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffae00, #d67600);background: linear-gradient(top, #ffae00, #d67600);border:2px outset #dad9d8;font-family:Andika, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:1.1em;letter-spacing:0.05em;text-transform:uppercase;color:#fff;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 10px #000;-webkit-border-radius: 15px;-moz-border-radius: 15px;border-radius: 15px;-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .55) 0 1px 6px;-moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .55) 0 1px 6px;
box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .55) 0 1px 6px;">
</td>
<td><input name="selector[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $get_data2['test_name'] ?>"></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

Comment: I have done the changes but still, selector could not able to get the values. I'm getting the value of "echo $N" as zero. Also the value of reason_failure_bulk and action_taken_bulk not shown after submitting.

Comment: Got Undefined index: selector error at $id = $_POST['selector'];

Comment: Have you put `<input name="selector[]"` inside form?

Comment: I got rid of it. It's because of Array to string exception. It working now!! Thanks for the help!